# HTTP POST multipart/form-data with setHTTPBody like .csv.gz

Tags: ios, http, post, gzip, multipartform-data

I need put an .csv compress with gzip. To do it:

```
NSString *boundary = @"*****";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:100];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

NSMutableData *theBodyData = [NSMutableData data];
[theBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name= \"server_value_name\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theBodyData appendData:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"9999999999997-d4a9-a5f2-87da-e564.csv.gz\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: file/csv\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theBodyData appendData:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[theBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *theBodyDataZip=[theBodyData gzippedData];


[request setHTTPBody:theBodyDataZip];

NSError *error = nil; NSURLResponse *response = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

The file is saved in the server but i can´t open it...

Some idea?

Thks for all.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, just replace the values in %%

```
POST %URI% HTTP/1.1 
Authorization:Basic ****
X-HostCommonName:%HOSTNAME%
MIME-Version:1.0 
Host:%HOST%
Content-Length:523 
X-Target-URI:%URI%
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; type="application/vnd.ms-excel"; start="&lt;file&gt;"; boundary="--0246824681357ACXZabcxyz" 
Connection:Keep-Alive

----0246824681357ACXZabcxyz 
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name="file"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 
Content-ID: <file> 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="usageFile.csv"
Content-Location: file
%BINARY DATA%
----0246824681357ACXZabcxyz--
```